# How to extract custom Lingui wrapper in React?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, linguijs

I created a custom Lingui wrapper in a React project:

```
function translate(translateObject: ITrenslatable) {
  const { i18n, id, fallback, values, comment } = translateObject;

  let translatedText = i18n._({
    id,
    message: fallback,
    values,
    comment,
  });

  if (translatedText == id) {
    translatedText = i18n._({
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      message: fallback,
      values,
      comment,
    });
  }

  return translatedText;
}
```

In the future, this custom wrapper may how additional features, and I'm also planning on making a `<Translate />` tag that uses the function above under the hood to achieve custom translating behavior.

Edit: currently I need this function because:

1. I want to create a layer of abstraction between my
   application and translation.
2. I need this wrapper function to be able to provide a default
   value, because otherwise if there were missing translations (e.g.
   translation only available in English, and not Hungarian, only the
   `id` would be displayed when switched to Hungarian).

The custom function works exactly as expected when used on already extracted text, but unfortunately, I cannot extract from this function.

It looks like this when used:

```
translate({
      i18n,
      fallback: "User at {id}",
      id: "user.title",
      values: { id: props.id },
})
```

How do I make Lingui find and extract my custom `translate` function?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Can you share an example of how you are using the function? im not sure i understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is already an example in the post. I also updated with why I need thus wrapper!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Lingui myself and did no try out this solution, but according to the [documentation](https://lingui.dev/guides/custom-extractor), what you should probably do is:

Create a custom extractor that parses your code and inserts `/*i18n*/` annotations to the calls of your `translate` function, so the parameters passed to this function can then be picked up by the default extractor:

```
import { extractor as defaultExtractor } from "@lingui/cli/api";

export const extractor: ExtractorType = {
  match(filename: string) {
    return defaultExtractor.match(filename);
  },
  extract(filename: string, code: string, onMessageExtracted, ctx: ExtractorCtx) {
    const annotatedCode = code.replace(/\btranslate\s*\(/, "translate( /*i18n*/ "
    return defaultExtractor.extract(filename, annotatedCode, onMessageExtracted, ctx);
  },
};
```

...and add your extractor to the `lingui.config.ts` file:

```
import { extractor } from './my-custom-extractor.ts'
module.exports = {
  [...]
  extractors: [extractor]
}
```

Please be aware that this is prone to some errors, e.g. if somebody choses to define an alias for the `translate` function like this, the extraction will not work:

```js
import {translate as t} from "your-package";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize how the lingui cli extracts strings, as documented here https://lingui.dev/ref/conf#runtimeconfigmodule

I understand that you want to have an abstraction layer, but looking at your example, I don't think what you're doing is a good idea, and I'd rather follow the approach recommended by the official docs.

Also, if your `if (translatedText == id)` condition is meant to detect untranslated strings, it's wrong - it will work only for simple use cases but not for plurals and other more complicated stuff.

To provide fallbacks, look at https://lingui.dev/ref/conf#fallbacklocales

Hope this helps! :)